# What is the easyjet hand luggage weight limit?

Tags: air-travel, airlines, hand-luggage, easyjet

I am looking for Easyjet hand luggage weight limit. As far as I remember they don't have one. I found a few blogs stating the same. I also checked their [website](http://www.easyjet.com/en/planning/baggage) and I didn't find any [reference](http://www.easyjet.com/en/planning/baggage). Is there a limit?

Answer (score 7):

There is a mention that there is no weight restriction on the Cabin baggage unless they [impose it separately per flight](http://www.easyjet.com/en/terms-and-conditions).

> 20.3.1 passengers are permitted one piece of Cabin Baggage which must comply with the following criteria:
>
> • the maximum dimensions of the Cabin Baggage may not be any larger
> than 56x45x25cm (including wheels, pockets and handles).  However, due
> to restrictions on available space in the aircraft cabin on many busy
> Flights, We reserve the right to place any Cabin Baggage in the hold
> which is bigger than 50x40x20cm (including handles, pockets and
> wheels), (See Cabin Baggage FAQ)
>
> • all Cabin Baggage must easily fit within the size dimensions of the
> Baggage size gauges provided at our Bag Drop desks at the airport and
> at the departure gates.
>
> • no weight restriction applies to the one
> item of Cabin Baggage within reasonable limits - i.e. a passenger must
> be able to place and retrieve the one item of Cabin Baggage safely in
> the overhead storage lockers without assistance. On occasion it may be
> necessary to impose a weight limit for operational reasons. In this
> instance Your Cabin Baggage will be placed in the aircraft hold at no
> additional charge provided You have complied with all applicable
> Baggage requirements and limitations contained in Our Terms and
> Conditions.
>
> • any handbag, briefcase and/or laptop bag must be
> carried within the allowance of one permitted piece of Cabin Baggage.
>
> • an overcoat, shawl, umbrella or walking stick and one bag of goods
> purchased after You have cleared the security screening point at the
> departure airport may also be carried in addition to the allowance of
> one item of Cabin Baggage.

Comment: If you have more than one item at boarding, being it shopping done in the airport or you starting out with more than one, you may be asked to gate check one of them. They can be very strict on the 'one item only' rule, not sure if it is written down but I have seen it happen.

Answer (score 3):

Easyjet still doesn't have weight limit. Just a size limit of 50x40x20cm. This [handy chart](http://maphappy.org/2015/01/watch-the-weight-of-carry-on-baggage/) outlines the baggage size and weight requirements for many European carriers. Pretty helpful for anyone heading over to Europe.